# A freed access type variable is supposed to be set to NULL; why does it keep the same address?

Tags: memory-management, ada

According to the Adacore website, once an access type variable is freed then it is set to `null`. Then why does the same address get printed before and after `Free`?

```
with ada.Text_IO,ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with ada.Unchecked_Deallocation;
with System.Address_Image;
procedure hello is
   type my_access is access all integer;
   procedure free is new ada.Unchecked_Deallocation(integer,my_access);
   var:my_access:=new integer;
begin
   ada.Text_IO.put_line(System.Address_Image(var'Address));   --- same address
   var.all:=90;
   ada.Integer_Text_IO.put(var.all);
   free(var); -- after free it is set to Null then why same address?
   ada.Text_IO.put_line(System.Address_Image(var'Address));  --- same address why?
end hello;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is an access variable that *points* to (or accesses) an integer.  The access variable `var` typically lives on the stack.  It typically uses 4 or 8 bytes of memory.  When `hello` is called, the program allocates an integer on the "heap", and sets `var` to point to the integer.  Therefore, `var` will **contain** the address of the new integer (the Ada language doesn't require that it actually contains the address, but in most implementations it will).  After you free it, `var` will **contain** `null`.

However, `var'address` doesn't give you the address of the integer, or the contents of the 4 or 8 byte pointer.  `var'address` is the address of the pointer **itself**--that is, the address of the 4 or 8 bytes it uses on the stack.

If you want to get the address of the integer, `var.all'address` will work unless `var` is `null`, and then an exception will be raised.  Another way to convert between an access value and an address is [`System.Address_To_Access_Conversions`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-7-2.html).  That works with the address of the `integer` that got allocated on the heap, not with the address of the access variable on the stack.